# Xamarin Forms - how do colors work on Navigation bar for iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to set the BarBackgroundColor and BarTextColor for a simple XF app, and am not understanding the output.  A picture of what I am seeing follows the code, and all the code can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/JohnLivermore/SampleXamarinApp/tree/navigationheaderissue).

I set BarBackgroundColor, BarTextColor, and BackgroundColor below.  It seems the only color (from the attached image) being set is the Color.Blue BarBackgroundColor.  Shouldn't the text in the navigation bar and status bar be White?  Why isn't the rest of the page Red?

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var navPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    navPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.Blue; 
    navPage.BarTextColor = Color.White;
    navPage.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;

    MainPage = navPage;
}
```

**XAML**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="SampleApp.MainPage">

    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                     VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="Page Title" />
        </StackLayout>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Here is the output I am getting.

[image]

Comment: the properties in your C# snippet refer to the standard navigation title view.  When you provide a custom TitleView like you do in your XAML, then you control all of the UI yourself.

Comment: Thank you. What about the status/carrier bar above?

Comment: There is no "status bar" in iOS in current versions afaik. The status bar is part of the navigation bar, if there is one, otherwise, its part of the entire view. You need to set a padding to start your view outside of the status line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Shouldn't the text in the navigation bar and status bar be White?

Yes , if code as shared , will not .

- **First** , we will check how to set the text color in the navigation bar .

Because setting custom title view in Navigation Bar as follow :

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                 VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Label Text="Page Title" />
    </StackLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

Then code  `navPage.BarTextColor = Color.White;` will not work .The reason is that , you set a custom title view in ContentPage ,and ContentPage Overrides the effect of the navigation bar text .

If want to show white color of Naviagtion Title , there are two ways based on shared code .

**One** is : Set `TextColor` for Label in custom title view .

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                 VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Label Text="Page Title" TextColor = "White" />
    </StackLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

**Another** is : Using original navigation bar title .

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="SampleApp.MainPage"
             Title="Page Title"> // Adding title text here

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Then code `navPage.BarTextColor = Color.White;` will work for text of naviagtion bar.

- **Second**, we will check how to set the text color in the status bar .

Here you need to enter iOS Solution folder, then open `Info.plist` file with Xml Editor as follow :

[image]

Then adding the Key **UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance** and set its value to `false` as follow.

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

Saving and rebuliding project , now code `navPage.BarTextColor = Color.White;` can work for 
text color of status bar .

> Why isn't the rest of the page Red?

This problem should be different for Android . If running `navPage.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;` in Android ,it will work.However will not in iOS.

The reason is that , Navigation Controller is different between Android and iOS. The Navigation Bar just a bar in Android , however Navigation Bar can be a whole Page view in iOS. That means if setting background color to NavigationPage in Android , it can work in Navigation Page and ContentPage. However , in iOS it only can work in Navigation page . If Want content page show different , you should individually set in Content page.

Therefore , setting as follow in iOS background color can be work.

//Adding background color here can work

```
<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

Final effect as follow:

[image]